# Name for addresses?

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, magento-community

I wanna ask you something about a possible "feature" that I have no idea if is easy to implement or not. In checkout page for example, we can see the addresses selectbox and the default address selected is displayed as following:

```
4806 Rustic Barn Farms, Tompkins, California, 95454-3246, US, (530) 954-4054
```

That is the default view for the address on the selectboxes. Most ecommerces use a field to give a "*label*" for each address, like "Home", "Uncle's house", "Office" etc, and the label is associated to that address and used during checkout process.

Is there some "easy" way to make that feature works in Magento?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new address attribute `label`
2. Ammend frontend as required so that customer can create/modify `label`
3. Update `System \ Configuration \ Admin \ Customers \ Customer Configuration \ Address Templates` such that the `address one-line` template only displays the `label` attribute.

I believe that should work.

Comment: Tell me how it goes!

Comment: It should be a native feature from Magento, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm not certain, google is your friend there. However my solution should still work. Are you confident enough in creating new address attributes etc?

Comment: I've searched and found some tutorials, because it's something new for me, but I guess it's easy. Take a look here: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/

Comment: Had a quick glance. That tutorial looks like it'll cover everything you need. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19936/discussion-between-luke-rodgers-and-joao-house).